# synchronize Photo with iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, photos.app

I recently reset my iPhone and I'm trying to synchronize my photo gallery to the iphone. Everything works fine when I try to import the photo from iphone but, it seems only the photo taken until last week are copied from Photo to iPhone. So, my iPhoto has 3500 photos but on the iphone, after the synchronization, I can see only 3000 (more or less) photo.

[image: This is how Itunes is configured]

What's wrong? I'm not using iCloud to sync the photo. Before the reset of the mobile, everything worked fine.

It's basically excluding pictures taken during last 7 days.

Comment: I assume there is enough space left on the iPhone for the remaining 500 pictures?

Comment: Yes, 50% of free space available.